# Что в коде angular делает @HostBinding()?

Tags: angular

```
    export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {
     @HostBinding('attr.class') cssClass = 'row';
     votes: number;
     title: string;
     link: string;
```

Есть код где используется  @HostBinding не могу понять что он делает, если можно доступно обясните в чем его предназначение, когда нужно его использовать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ангуляре есть такое понятие, как `host` - это элемент, соответствующий селектору указанному в свойстве `selector` в декораторах `@Component` и `@Directive`.

Например для `selector: 'my-app'` хостом будет элемент `<my-app>`

Декораторы [`@HostBinding`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) и [`@HostListener`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) позволяют устанавливать свойства и обработчики событий непосредственно хосту.

Например:

```
@HostBinding('attr.class') cssClass = 'row';
```

Приведет к тому, что у хост элемента будет установлен атрибут `class` со значением `row`, т.е. если был указан `selector: 'article'`, то все элементы `<article>` примут вид `<article class="row">`

`@HostListener` действует аналогично, но для обработчиков событий, например `click`.

[**Небольшой пример**](https://angular-2e5emw.stackblitz.io)